# Parse large RDF stream in Java using Jena

Tags: java, parsing, rdf, jena, large-files

I need something like

`Triple readNextTriple(stream)`

so that I can process the triple one by one.

It is difficult to find an instruction for this task in `Jena`.

It seems that all options lead to a `model.read()`, which read the whole stream at once.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

See `StreamRDF` and `RDFdataMgr`.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/streaming-io.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.  But I am really a novice. Could you please explain a little bit clearer ? An example would be very appreciated.

Comment: @YumiF, there's example code in the link provided. There's also the Jena API Javadoc which clearly explains what the various classes and methods do. Why don't you try a few things out? If you get stuck, feel free to come back and ask a new question (explaining clearly what you're trying to do and where exactly you're stuck).